# How to make two https calls in single controller on page load Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS

I am trying to make two API calls on page load but I want to do one after another once I got the response I want to call another Asynchronous calls. my service looks as below

can you please suggest me what should be the best way to achieve this.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";
   var APIservice = function($http,$base64,UtilService,$rootScope){
         UtilService.setHeaders($rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata);
        var DataProvider = function(method,url,data){
            return $http({
                       method: method,
                       url: url,
                       data:data
                  }).then(function(response){
                     console.log(response);
                        return response.data;
                    });
        };
        return {
            DataProvider:DataProvider
        }
   }
   var module = angular.module('expframework');
   module.factory("APIservice",APIservice);
}());
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Just use promise chaining:

```
APIservice.DataProvider('GET', firstUrl).then(function(data1) {
    return APIservice.DataProvider('GET', secondUrl);
}).then(function(data2) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: At the same time I wanted to use the same call backs for success and error cases. Is it possible?

Comment: You'd better edit your question and explain what you really want to achieve, with a concrete example. Because what you're asking is unclear to me. But yes, you can define a function, and use it as success and error callback.